# Grouping similar values in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm not well-versed in SQL but have started to work on a project using spark SQL.

I have a view with a floating point column, say the first 10 rows look something like this:

```
idx | col1
---------
 0  | 0.0
 1  | 0.0
 2  | 0.384
 3  | 0.383
 4  | 0.382 
 5  | 0.384
 6  | 0.518
 7  | 0.524
 8  | 0.520
 9  | 0.250
```

I need to build groups of rows containing similar values in `col1`. Similar means below x%, e.g. 5%, of the previous value. For these rows, I want to assign a "group index", which increases when going through rows. So, in the above example, the result of my operation should be:

```
idx | col1  | col2
-------------------
 0  | 0.0   | 0
 1  | 0.0   | 0
 2  | 0.384 | 1
 3  | 0.383 | 1
 4  | 0.382 | 1
 5  | 0.384 | 1
 6  | 0.518 | 2
 7  | 0.524 | 2
 8  | 0.520 | 2
 9  | 0.250 | 3
```

I know the window operation `LAG`, but am overchallenged in applying it in this context.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to proceed?

Thank you!

PS: eventually, the goal would be to compute the average of `col1` within each of these groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most optimal, but set the idx as group number when the margin is not met. Then do a forward fill on the missing values. Probably easier to read in two steps, but anyways...:

`last_value(if (col1 between lag(col1, 1) over(order by idx) * 0.95 and lag(col1, 1) over(order by idx) * 1.05, null, idx), true) over (order by idx rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as group`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Somehow my notification ended up in spam and I found it just now. Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you so much and again apologies for the late reply!